# Proof of MacPherson's result about set-valued constructible sheaves and exit paths

Tags: reference-request, homotopy-theory, constructible-sheaves, stratifications

I'm looking for a proof of a theorem that is attributed to MacPherson. Treumann (Section 1.1 in [Exit paths and constructible stacks, 2009)](https://doi.org/10.1112/S0010437X09004229) states the theorem as:

> Theorem 1.2 (MacPherson). Let $(X,S)$ be a topologically stratified
>   space. The category of $S$-constructible sheaves of sets is equivalent
>   to the category $\text{Funct}(EP_{\leqslant 1}(X, S), \text{Sets})$ of
>   $\text{Sets}$-valued functors on $EP_{\leqslant 1} (X, S)$.

Here $EP_{\leqslant 1}$ is the category of exit paths. He does not provide a proof, and earlier mentions

> MacPherson (unpublished) observed that, for a fixed stratification $S$
>   of $X$, it is possible to give a description of the $S$-constructible
>   sheaves on $X$ in terms of monodromy along certain paths.

So it seems the proof has not been published by MacPherson, but maybe someone else has written it down, and I would be very glad to see it. Barwick-Glasman-Haine (Introduction in [Exodromy, 2018](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.03281v1)) similarly say

> Bob MacPherson proved that constructible sheaves of sets on a
>   (suitably nice) stratified [topological space] $X$ over a poset $P$
>   determine and are determined by a functor from the exit-path category.

No reference is given here. Ayala-Francis-Rozenblyum prove a similar version of MacPherson's theorem with functors into spaces (Corollary 3.3.11 in [A stratified homotopy hypothesis, 2017](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.01713v4)), but they require $X$ to be a "conically smooth stratified space," which I would like to not impose. The most general case (I think) is given by Lurie (Theorem A.9.3 in [Higher Algebra, 2017](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/papers/HA.pdf)), which is my motivation here - in trying to understand Lurie's proof I am looking for a proof to MacPherson's statement.

Worth mentioning is that MacPherson considers actual paths and $\text{Set}$-valued functors, Treumann paths, 2-simplices and $\text{Cat}$-valued functors, and the rest use all dimensions and functors valued in spaces. I am specifically looking for a proof of the 1-dimensional $\text{Set}$-valued case (I understand that Treumann's and Lurie's proofs contain this case, but I guess I don't yet trust my own skills to pick out only the necessary pieces).

Comment: [This paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.01587) of Curry and Patel is pretty accessible and detailed, and focuses on the 1-categorical situation. It does restrict itself to the conically stratified case (which in most situations one cares about is satisfied anyway).